# Getting The connection was reset error message ?

Tags: php, facebook

I getting this error message suddendly and i don't know why because my fb app ran perfectly. My hosting guy said the he moved my site to another server, but he kept the same configuration.

this is my facebook app code:

```
    include 'config.php';
    $user = $facebook->getUser();
    echo $user; 

    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array ( 
            'scope' => 'publish_actions,public_profile,user_friends',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://attila-naghi.com/fb/mytest/test.php'
    ));

    echo '<a href = "'.$loginUrl.'">Login Here </a> ';
```

and this is the test.php file:

```
$user = $facebook->getUser();  // here it crashed for some god know reason
    if ($user) {
        try{
            $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
            $fbid = $user_profile['id'];                 // To Get Facebook ID
            $fbfullname = $user_profile['name']; // To Get Facebook full name
            $femail = $user_profile['email'];    // To Get Facebook email ID

            //FACEBOOK POST
        }catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            error_log($e);
            $user = null;
        }
........
```

I created a new facebook application, but still the same. I moved in another folder the but still the same. I'm out of idea why I'm still getting this. Can you give some idea ? thx

Comment: Can you post the whole error message?  Also we have no way of knowing what $facebook->getUser(); does exactly but changing folders probably won't do much good, sry.

Comment: the result is the connection was reset if I put an exit after the line of code where i put the comment

Comment: I'm having a similiar issue, it might be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998981/post-redirect-throws-a-connection-was-reset-browser-error

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark, but do you have php CURL installed on your new server? Usually request such as these require some back and forth which usually comes in the form of a CURL request, but there are other ways :)

Comment: see the phpinfo result here : http://attila-naghi.com/fb/mytest/ it is installed, but maybe you can tell me more

Comment: Sry @Maria if you have CURL installed, which you do, then it is more than likely making the request, however that doesn't mean it is "successful".  With FB app there are all kinds of security hoops to jump through before you can get something like this running.  SO next up try adding `print_r($e);` just after `catch (FacebookApiException $e) {` and see what it says.  Also post here if you need help.